For what $q$, $r$ does $x^2(x-1)^2(x-2)=-p(x-q)^2(x-r)^2$ have $5$ distinct real roots $\forall~p$

Let $f(x)=x^2(x-1)^2(x-2)$ and $g(x)=-p(x-q)^2(x-r)^2$ where $0<p$ and $0<q<r$. Find the set of values of $q$ and $r$ such that the equation $f(x)=g(x)$ has $5$ distinct real roots for all $p$.

This is TMUA problem 18 in 2022. A solution can be found here.
A graphic method is used, but I suppose that graphs can lead to mistakes if not properly drawn (how deep exactly is each "valley"?). So I would like to ask for an algebraic method.
My idea is to first eliminate the cases where $q$ or $r$ equals to $1$ or $2$. Then we have
$$\frac{x^2(x-1)^2(x-2)}{(x-q)^2(x-r)^2}=-p.$$
We may derive this perhaps. But I cannot proceed.

Do not use graphs anymore. Also, the answer is $q<1$, $1<r<2$.

Perhaps $f'(x)-g'(x)=0$ has 4 different solution so $f''(x)-g''(x)=0$ has 3 different solution so ...

@nonuser That is indeed a necessary condition. I will try it.

"Find the set of values of $p$ and $q$ such that ... for all $p$? Maybe one of those $p$'s should be an $r$?

@RobertIsrael You are right. We need to find the range of $q$ and $r$.
